# Proper way to include unnumbered chapters in a per-chapter bibliography using biblatex

Tags: sectioning, biblatex, subdividing, starred-version

I've been using example `3.11.4` of the `biblatex` documentation to generate a per-chapter bibliography at the end of my thesis. It works great, until I try to make my introduction into an unnumbered chapter. Then, the introduction does not appear in the bibliography. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[sorting = none, style = numeric, refsegment = chapter, cite reset = chapter]{bib latex}
\usepackage{nameref}

\defbibheading{bibintoc}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
  \section*{References for Chapter \ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment} - \nameref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\cite{A01}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\cite{A01,B02}

\backmatter

\printbibheading
\bibbysegment[heading = bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

I found a work-around, using a refsection for the unnumbered Introduction. Here's a MWE of the workaround:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[sorting = none, style = numeric, refsegment = chapter, cite reset = chapter]{bib latex}
\usepackage{nameref}

\defbibheading{bibintoc}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
  \section*{References for Chapter \ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment} - \nameref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}}

\defbibheading{bibintoc2}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
  \section*{References for the \nameref{refsection:\therefsection}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\begin{refsection}
\cite{A01}
\end{refsection}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\cite{A01,B02}

\backmatter

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[section=1,heading=bibintoc2]
\bibbysegment[heading = bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

I was content with this until I added an unnumbered Conclusion with citations. Then the code breaks down and `biblatex` returns a `nested refsections` error. Here's the MWE for that:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[sorting = none, style = numeric, refsegment = chapter, cite reset = chapter]{bib latex}
\usepackage{nameref}

\defbibheading{bibintoc}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
  \section*{References for Chapter \ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment} - \nameref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}}

\defbibheading{bibintoc2}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
  \section*{References for the \nameref{refsection:\therefsection}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\begin{refsection}
\cite{A01}
\end{refsection}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\cite{A01,B02}

\chapter*{Conclusion}
\begin{refsection}
\cite{C03}
\end{refsection}

\backmatter

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[section=1,heading=bibintoc2]
\bibbysegment[heading = bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Or, even better, how to properly implement `\chapter*` with example `3.11.4` of the `biblatex` doc?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can invoke `\newrefsegment` and `\citereset` manually in the unnumbered chapters:

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\newrefsegment
\citereset
```

but the titles for the bibliography segments can't be formatted consistently. There are various ways around this. Here we handle everything with patches to both `\chapter` and `\chapter*`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[sorting=none,refsegment=chapter,citereset=chapter]{biblatex}
\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
% Extend biblatex's \chapter patch to \chapter* and save data for titles
\def\blx@refpatch@chapter#1{%
  \ifundef\chapter
    {\blx@err@nodocdiv{chapter}}
    {\pretocmd\@makechapterhead
       {#1%
        \csdef{subbib:\therefsection\therefsegment}{%
          Chapter~\ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}}
       {}{\blx@err@patch{\string\@makechapterhead}}%
     \pretocmd\@makeschapterhead
       {#1%
        \csdef{subbib:\therefsection\therefsegment}{%
          \nameref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}}
       {}{\blx@err@patch{\string\@makeschapterhead}}}}
\makeatother
\defbibheading{subbibliography}{%
  \section*{References for \csuse{subbib:\therefsection\therefsegment}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Introduction}
\cite{reese}
\chapter{First chapter}
\cite{companion}
\chapter*{Unnumbered chapter}
\cite{glashow,weinberg}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\cite{glashow}
\chapter*{Conclusion}
\cite{reese}
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\bibbysegment[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This approach also works for reference sections by chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[sorting=none,refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
% Extend biblatex's \chapter patch to \chapter*, save data for titles
\def\blx@refpatch@chapter#1{%
  \ifundef\chapter
    {\blx@err@nodocdiv{chapter}}
    {\pretocmd\@makechapterhead
       {#1\csdef{subbib:\therefsection}{Chapter~\ref{refsection:\therefsection}}}
       {}{\blx@err@patch{\string\@makechapterhead}}%
     \pretocmd\@makeschapterhead
       {#1\csdef{subbib:\therefsection}{\nameref{refsection:\therefsection}}}
       {}{\blx@err@patch{\string\@makeschapterhead}}}}
\makeatother
\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\section*{References for \csuse{subbib:\therefsection}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
...
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\bibbysection[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I had in mind. However, this solution seems to break `\citereset`. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @Kpantzas That seems unlikely. Switching the style to `verbose` and playing around with the `citereset` settings or `\citereset` in the above document doesn't demonstrate any issues.

Comment: Well then I guess I haven't understood `citereset`. I thought that it was used to reset citations so that they would start from [1] after each reset (in this case each chapter). This is not the behavior I'm getting with your example. Though now that I think about it, this would be incompatible with `refsegment` and I should use `refsection` instead... any thoughts about that?

Comment: @Kpantzas `\citereset` only resets the citation trackers. For independent labelnumbers you should be using reference sections, not segments. I've updated the post to demonstrate the approach with `refsection=chapter`.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `\endrefsegment` to manually terminate the last segment before the unnumbered "Conclusion"  chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[sorting = none, style = numeric, refsegment = chapter, cite reset = chapter]{bib latex}
\usepackage{nameref}

\defbibheading{bibintoc}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
  \section*{References for Chapter \ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment} - \nameref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}}

\defbibheading{bibintoc2}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
  \section*{References for the \nameref{refsection:\therefsection}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\begin{refsection}
\cite{A01}
\end{refsection}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\cite{A01,B02}

\endrefsegment

\chapter*{Conclusion}
\begin{refsection}
\cite{C03}
\end{refsection}

\backmatter

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[section=1,heading=bibintoc2]
\bibbysegment[heading = bibintoc]
\printbibliography[section=2,heading=bibintoc2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

While this solves your immediate problem, your workaround of using `refsection`s for the Introduction and Conclusion results in completely independent bibliography labels for these chapters (note how the work of C. Cuthor is assigned the label "1" in the Conclusion). The following solution works only with `refsegment`s (and hereby achieves labels unique for the whole document):

- Don't use the starred version `\chapter*` but `\chapter` *also* for the Introduction and Conclusion. This way, a (positive) `refsegment` number will be assigned to these chapters, and their respective references can be printed using `\bibbysegment`.
- Use `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` to make the Introduction and Conclusion non-numbered chapters. (Actually, use `\boolfalse{@mainmatter}` instead of `\frontmatter` to avoid switching to Roman page numbering.)
- Declare new counters to store the value of `\therefsegment` after the front- resp. the mainmatter, and use these counters in a new definition of the `bibintoc2` heading to achieve the different format for front-/main-/backmatter references.

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[sorting=none,style =numeric,refsegment=chapter,citereset=chapter]{biblatex}
\usepackage{nameref}

\newcounter{segmentendfront}
\newcounter{segmentendmain}

\defbibheading{bibintoc2}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\refname}%
  \section*{\refname\ for
    \ifnumgreater{\therefsegment}{\value{segmentendfront}}{%
      \ifnumgreater{\therefsegment}{\value{segmentendmain}}{%
        the
      }{%
        Chapter~\ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment} --
      }%
    }{%
      the
    }%
    \nameref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\boolfalse{@mainmatter}% instead of \frontmatter, which would also switch
    %to Roman page numbering

\chapter{Introduction}

\cite{A01}

\mainmatter
\setcounter{segmentendfront}{\therefsection\therefsegment}

\chapter{First chapter}

\cite{A01,B02}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\cite{B02}

\backmatter
\setcounter{segmentendmain}{\therefsection\therefsegment}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\cite{C03}

\printbibheading
\bibbysegment[heading=bibintoc2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While this does work, it kind of feels wrong to place the intro and conclusion in the `frontmatter` and `backmatter` respectively. Especially since there already is a `frontmatter` (toc,lof,lot,acknowledgements, preface) and a `backmatter` (bibliography, appendices, glossaries), that I'd like to separate from the main text of the thesis. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do this:

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\begin{refsegment}
\cite{A01}
\end{refsegment}
```

Edit: The problem with the refsegment for the conclusion is not that there is a second refsegment but that with the option `refsegment=chapter` a `\chapter` command inserts a `\begin{refsegment}` (or something analog) and this isn't closed by the `\chapter*.

You could stop this segment before the conclusion:

```
\endrefsegment

\chapter*{Conclusion}
```

(A better solution would be to patch `\chapter*` too).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yep, I tried that too, the `nested refsection` becomes a `nested refsegment` error

Comment: Sorry I had used the wrong code for testing and so overlooked the conclusion problem. I have edited the answer.