# biblatex per-chapter bibliography and titlesec

Tags: sectioning, biblatex, titlesec, subdividing

This is a follow-up to my previous question [Proper way to include unnumbered chapters in a per chapter bibliography using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69320/proper-way-to-include-unnumbered-chapters-in-a-per-chapter-bibliography-using-bi).

The solution proposed by Audrey breaks when I use the `titlesec` package to modify the chapter headings. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{titlesec}           
\usepackage{titletoc}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage[style = phys,%
            sorting=none,%
            backend=biber,%
            style=numeric,%
            hyperref=auto,%
            backref = true,%
            refsection=chapter,%
%           citereset=chapter,%
            dateabbrev=false,%
            urldate=comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
% Extend biblatex's \chapter patch to \chapter*
\def\blx@refpatch@chapter#1{%
  \ifundef\chapter
    {\blx@err@nodocdiv{chapter}}
    {\pretocmd\@makechapterhead
       {#1}{}{\blx@err@patch{\string\@makechapterhead}}%
     \pretocmd\@makeschapterhead
       {#1}{}{\blx@err@patch{\string\@makeschapterhead}}}}
% Save data for bibliography titles
\apptocmd\@makechapterhead
  {\csdef{subbib:\therefsection}{%
     Chapter~\ref{refsection:\therefsection} - \nameref{refsection:\therefsection}}}{}{}
\apptocmd\@makeschapterhead
  {\csdef{subbib:\therefsection}{%
     \nameref{refsection:\therefsection}}}{}{}

\makeatother

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{%
  \section*{References for \csuse{subbib:\therefsection}}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\bfseries \LARGE \bfseries }{ \thechapter}{0.75em}{}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{0cm}{0.6cm}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\begin{refsegment}
\cite{A01}
\end{refsegment}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\cite{A01,B02}

\chapter*{Conclusion}
\begin{refsegment}
\cite{C03}
\end{refsegment}

\backmatter

\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\bibbysection[heading = subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

The result in the bibliography is this:

[image]

As you can see the references to the chapters have disappeared. There not even any question marks. I guess this means that the `\csuse{subbib:\therefsection}}` portion of the solution by Audrey points towards nothing after I insert the redefinition of the chapter format using `titlesec`'s `\titleformat`.

Also, putting the `\titleformat{...}` redefinition of the chapter headings before the biblatex patch ends in the following error `argument of \csdef has an extra }`.

Any ideas how to work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appending the chapter macros is likely the problem. You can move the control sequence definitions for the titles just after `biblatex`'s prepending patch.

```
\def\blx@refpatch@chapter#1{%
  \ifundef\chapter
    {\blx@err@nodocdiv{chapter}}
    {\pretocmd\@makechapterhead
       {#1\csdef{subbib:\therefsection}{Chapter~\ref{refsection:\therefsection}}}
       {}{\blx@err@patch{\string\@makechapterhead}}%
     \pretocmd\@makeschapterhead
       {#1\csdef{subbib:\therefsection}{\nameref{refsection:\therefsection}}}
       {}{\blx@err@patch{\string\@makeschapterhead}}}}
```